# jQuery slider with fade not changing image

Tags: jquery, css, slider, fadein, jquery-slider

Am trying to create a simple JQuery Slider. And each time only one picture should be visible. And after x seconds a new image shoud fade in.
Only the problem is that the images are not displayed and lingers at the first picture.
Maybe someone can help me with this.

Code so far:
HTML

```
 <div id="slideshow">
    <span>
        <div class="vHolder">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" /> 
        </div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div class="vHolder">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
        </div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div class="vHolder">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
        </div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div class="vHolder">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow img:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow img:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 2500 );
});
```

And my working jsfiddle: http://goo.gl/4AvUcr

Comment: I don't think next is targeting the next image like you want it to. I think next grabs the next sibling and in that case there is no sibling because its wrapped in a div and a span. Maybe  a better approach is the give each img a data attribute pertaining to its order, then target that data attribute and increment it by one each time, once the length (last data attribute) has been reached reset the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider is not working because you are using next in the wrong way: next is a sibling selector so the next sibling for the img is going to be itself as there are no other elements in the div with the image.

If you change your code to remove the span tags wrapping the divs (not sure why you have these and it is invalid code), you can use the following:

```js
function slideSwitch() {
  var $active = $('#slideshow .active');

  if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow > div:last');

  var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow > div:first');

  $active.addClass('last-active');

  $next.css({
      opacity: 0.0
    })
    .animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function() {
      $next.addClass('active')
    });

  $active.css({
      opacity: 1.0
    })
    .animate({
      opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });


}

$(function() {
  setInterval("slideSwitch()", 2500);
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}

#slideshow .vHolder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

#slideshow img {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="vHolder" class="active">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/1" alt="Slideshow Image 1" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="vHolder">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/2" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="vHolder">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/3" alt="Slideshow Image 3" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="vHolder">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/4" alt="Slideshow Image 4" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! But how does the code changes when the images are wrapped with "a hrefs" ?

Comment: I have changed the above to work with anchors, you will note I have moved the active class from the image to the containing div

Comment: thanks a lot. How do I create a smooth opacity change between the slides?

Comment: What do you mean by smooth?  if you run the snippet above, it looks pretty smooth to me.  You may want to play around with the animation and interval speed if it is not smooth enough